# yml: how to make correct break without adding new line symbol

Tags: yaml

I have a piece of yml configuration (ansible)

```
  - name: my task_
    include_tasks: other_tasks.yml
    with_items:
      - { par1: "/usr/bin/",
          par2: "/usr/bin/test/",
          par3: >-
                   my string which does not 
                   pass validation
                   
          par4: "/usr/",
          par5: "/bin"
         }
```

And I'm trying to break a line (par3) without adding a new line symbol, but it does not
work

```
(<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 6 column 26
```

so, basically I have a long string, i.e

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

and I want to break it
"testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest" + "testtesttesttesttesttest"

without any new line symbols in between, but it just does not work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a long brute force session I found out that it should be like this

```
  - name: my task_
    include_tasks: other_tasks.yml
    with_items:
      - { par1: "/usr/bin/",
          par2: "/usr/bin/test/",
          par3: "my string which does not\ 
          pass validation",  
          par4: "/usr/",
          par5: "/bin"
         }
```

Mind the `\`